# How to [properly] correlate environmental variables to NMDS ordination axes?

Tags: r, correlation, normality-assumption, pearson-r, multidimensional-scaling

Data + setup:

- I've constructed an NMDS ordination from a Bray-Curtis distance matrix calculated from relativized abundances (basal areas) of trees. Samples include ~40 forested plots that have been resampled 13-15 times each.
- I also have ~60 environmental variables (soil, topography, etc.) that were measured from each plot in the last sampling year. Many variables relate and/or are correlated to one another.

Goal:

- I want to determine if any of my environmental variables explain the NMDS structure and if so to what degree.

Attempt:

- I opted to use `vf()` from the [ecodist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ecodist/ecodist.pdf) package in R (though I know a lot of people use `envfit()` or [`ordisurf`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/59170/80624) functions from the [`vegan`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/vegan.pdf) package). - From the help page, `vf` provides the following:

  > matrix with the first 2 columns containing the scores for every
  > variable in each of the 2 dimensions of the ordination space. r is the maximum correlation of the
  > variable with the ordination space, and pval is the result of the permutation test.
- Actually, all of these functions generate either a Pearson's r or an R<sup>2</sup>.

Concern

- Many of my environmental variables are non-normally distributed (and are not made normal via log transformation).

  - As [tested with QQ plots, histograms, and Shapiro-Wilk test](https://www.statology.org/test-for-normality-in-r/)
- My NMDS ordination scores (i.e., the sample point coordinates in my NMDS plot) are themselves not normally distributed (but of course, why would they be?!)

**QUESTIONS:**

**1. Is a Pearson correlation appropriate for assessing the correlation between any [non-normal] environmental variable and the NMDS axes?**

- **If so, do I have to transform any data to make it work??**

  - If yes, I don't think it makes sense to transform the ordination axes, so what do I do?

2. Given #1, What is the appropriate way to determine these correlations?

Comment: I'm asking because other questions regarding normality and correlation testing received what to me don't feel consistent/definitive. (especially for my particular NMDS application) . E.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/323011/80624, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/38273/80624, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/575185/80624, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/80624, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/231829/80624, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/160646/80624